# Reversing a Depth First Search or Pre-order traversal

Tags: graph, traversal, depth-first-search, tree-traversal

Let's say I have a complete binary graph of height 2, something like this:

```
         0
     1        2 
  3     4  5     6
```

where there's an edge from 0 to 1 and 0 to 2, 1 to 3 and 1 to 4, 2 to 5, and 2 to 6.

I can get the nodes in depth first search order (0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6) by doing a pre-order traversal.

Is there some reasonably simple way to algorithmically get the reverse from the pre-order traversal, post order traversal, or in-order traversal, by which I mean at each level you go right first, then left so you end up with (0, 2, 6, 5, 1, 4, 3)?

I've looked around a fair amount and haven't found anything applicable.

N.B. in case you are wondering why I want it I have a search algorithm that is based off of DFS and so find nodes that are more to the left of the graph more quickly than nodes on right.  I'm thinking about running parallel processes one on the normal left to right dfs and the other on a right to left reversal.

Answer (score 0):

In DFS you call the recursive function on the left leaf, and continue to do so until you cannot, and then one level up you call it on the right leaf, and then continue calling it on the left leaves all the way down.

Instead just switch every left with a right and every right with a left and then you can traverse every right leaf, and only traverse the left leaves when you can not longer traverse through the right leaves.

Comment: Sure as an algorithmic replacement of DFS, my question was specifically if you can get it from the traversals themselves.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand the question

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, if I hand you the three common DFS traversals of a graph (in-, post-, and pre-order) is there some way to get the "reverse" DFS list I suggest above?  Getting the normal DFS list of nodes is just the pre-order traversal, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are.

Depth first traversal (DFT) basically works like the following:

```
#include <vector>
struct TreeNode {
     std::vector<TreeNode*> children;
     // int data; optional data
}

void preorder(TreeNode* root) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        for (auto& child: root->children) {
            // visit(child); your arbitrary visit function
            preorder(child);
    }
}
```

Since the trees dont have loops, it will still work without recording the visited nodes. This will output (0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6) if you were to print the data in your visit function.

Now, instead of starting to search from the beginning of the children array, if you start from the end of that array, you will get the order you want, and it will work on any tree:

```
void reverse_preorder(TreeNode* root) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        for (int i = root->children.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
             // visit(root->children[i]); your arbitrary visit function
            reverse_preorder(root->children[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This will output (0, 2, 6, 5, 1, 4, 3) instead.